# TFS Jenkin's Plugin deletes already existing workspace mapping

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins, tfs-2015

I am trying to use the same TFS workspace for all my jobs, for some reason Jenkins TFS plugin seems to be deleting the existing workspace and creating a new workspace with new mapping.

'Hudson-Master' is the TFS workspace name

```
Warning: Although the server thinks the workspace exists, no mapping was found.
Deleting workspaces named 'Hudson-MASTER' from computer 'xxxxxxxxx'...
Deleted 1 workspace(s) named 'Hudson-MASTER'.
Creating workspace 'Hudson-MASTER'
```

[image: eclipse Screenshot]

thanks
Abdul Kader

Comment: This behavior comes from the line 102 of this file. It seems the server can't find the workspace based on your localpath.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I had just posted 4 lines, not sure of the 102 you are speaking about.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I am able to see the mapping in eclipse but the same mapping is deleted in second job

Comment: Forget to add the link, [line102](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/aea4ce0f1fd82668b1ead7e2aade2ffe36a32a10/tfs/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/tfs/actions/CheckoutAction.java#L102). Here's the open source repo of where your error message comes, maybe it can help for your trouble-shooting.

Comment: I can't say it's a good idea to share a workspace across jobs; it somewhat implicitly (generally) limits you to running one job at a time or you may see unexpected results. YMMV.  Having the same workspace used by Eclipse and Jenkins is definitely not good. Nevertheless, have you tried choosing the option "`[ X ] Use update`" ? All jobs should be connecting via the same account as there is a local workspace cache as well. in the home directory.

Comment: @lan W, i have application and their dependencies residing in different folder and there is no way for me to check out those specfic directories. Only way is to create  separate work space for each and each job's workspace has the entire TFS repsotiry residing in the works directory.